# One word for very helpful

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, american-english, synonyms

I was looking for a single word to express the sentence:

> You have been very helpful.

Is there a single word replacement for **very helpful** 
I understand that very is an intensifier here used with the adjective helpful. Will saying 
**You have been accommodating** convey the meaning properly?

Answer (score 1):

The word *accommodating* doesn't incorporate the intensifier, though it's a good word. Consider that you can say "You have been very accommodating."

A word that won't accept an additional intensifier is *indispensable*. It's not exactly the same as *helpful*, but it might fit some situations.